# Thread Break on Tag-Based Multi-Function UIButton changing UILabel

Tags: ios, multithreading, nsstring, uibutton, uilabel

I have a UIButton which has multiple methods.  As you will see in my code, each time you press the UIButton it changes its tag, thus letting me make it do a different thing each time (so the first time it does thing A, the second time thing B, etc.).  I did discover that for some reason the iPhone does two such methods at a time, so I added a useless method in-between each real one.  This was working perfectly but for some reason it just stopped working, and I have no idea why.  Now it gets a thread break on the very first UIButton press.  Any help is appreciated.

ViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController  <UITextViewDelegate> {
    IBOutlet UITextView *textEnterView;
    IBOutlet UILabel *promptLabel;
    IBOutlet UIButton *nextButton;

    NSString *topicString;
    NSString *firstString;
    NSString *firstSubString;
    NSString *secondString;
    NSString *secondSubString;
    NSString *thirdString;
    NSString *thirdSubString;
    NSString *conclusionString;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextView *textEnterView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *promptLabel;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIButton *nextButton;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *topicString;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *firstString;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *firstSubString;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *secondString;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *secondSubString;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *thirdString;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *thirdSubString;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *conclusionString;


- (IBAction) next:(id)sender;
@end
```

ViewController.m:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize textEnterView, promptLabel, nextButton, firstSubString, firstString, secondSubString, secondString, thirdSubString, thirdString, conclusionString, topicString;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    UIButton *button = nextButton;
    [button setTag:1234];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(next:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    textEnterView.delegate = self;
    promptLabel.text = @"First Label";
    textEnterView.text = @" ";
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}
- (IBAction) next:(UIButton *)sender {
    if(nextButton.tag==1234) {
    promptLabel.text = @"Second Label";
        [nextButton setTag:2];
        topicString = textEnterView.text;
        //FAKE METHOD
    }
    else if (nextButton.tag==2) {
        promptLabel.text = @"Third Label";
        textEnterView.text = @" ";
        [nextButton setTag:3];
        //REAL METHOD
    }
    else if (nextButton.tag==3) {
        promptLabel.text = @"Fourth Label";
        firstString = textEnterView.text;
        [nextButton setTag:4];
        //FAKE METHOD
    }
    else if (nextButton.tag==4) {
        promptLabel.text = @"Fifth Label";
        textEnterView.text = @" ";
        [nextButton setTag:5];
        //REAL METHOD
    }

    else if (nextButton.tag==5) {
        promptLabel.text = @"Sixth Label";
        firstSubString = textEnterView.text;
        [nextButton setTag:6];
        //FAKE METHOD
    }
    else if (nextButton.tag==6) {
        promptLabel.text = @"Seventh Label";
        textEnterView.text = @" ";
        [nextButton setTag:7];
        //REAL METHOD
    }
    else if (nextButton.tag==7) {
        promptLabel.text = @"Eighth Label";
        secondString = textEnterView.text;
        [nextButton setTag:8];
        //FAKE METHOD
    }
    else if (nextButton.tag==8) {
        promptLabel.text = @"Ninth Label";
        textEnterView.text = @" ";
        [nextButton setTag:9];
    //REAL METHOD
    }
    else if (nextButton.tag==9) {
        promptLabel.text = @"Tenth Label";
        secondSubString = textEnterView.text;
        [nextButton setTag:10];
    //FAKE METHOD
    }
    else if (nextButton.tag==10) {
        promptLabel.text = @"Eleventh Label";
        textEnterView.text = @" ";
        [nextButton setTag:11];
    //REAL METHOD
    }
    else if (nextButton.tag==11) {
        promptLabel.text = @"Twelfth Label";
        thirdString = textEnterView.text;
        [nextButton setTag:12];
    //FAKE METHOD
    }
    else if (nextButton.tag==12) {
        promptLabel.text = @"Thirteenth Label";
        textEnterView.text = @" ";
        [nextButton setTag:13];
    //REAL METHOD
    }
    else if (nextButton.tag==13) {
        promptLabel.text = @"Fourteenth Label";
        thirdSubString = textEnterView.text;
        [nextButton setTag:14];
    //FAKE METHOD
    }
    else if (nextButton.tag==14) {
        promptLabel.text = @"Fifteenth Label";
        textEnterView.text = @" ";
        [nextButton setTag:15];
    //REAL METHOD
    }
    else if (nextButton.tag==15) {
        promptLabel.text = @"Sixteenth Label";
        conclusionString = textEnterView.text;
        [nextButton setTag:16];
    }
    else if (nextButton.tag==16) {
        promptLabel.text = @"Seventeenth Label";
        textEnterView.text = @" ";
        [nextButton setTag:17];
    }
    else if (nextButton.tag==17) {
        [nextButton setTag:18];
    }
    else {
        promptLabel.text = @"Eighteenth Label";
        [nextButton setTag:1234];
    }

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Obviously the labels say something besides just "eighteenth label," but if I showed what why said it would I've away the idea of the app.  However, all the rest of the code is exactly as it is in the app.  Thank you for any help!

Comment: I'd start by stripping out the fakes.  You can simply change the tag in the touch up event.

Comment: I think I did change the tag in the touch up event... I don't understand why it does two methods at a time, but would happily delete the fakes if you can elaborate a bit about what you mean.  Where should I be setting the tag?  Do you just mean that my setting of the tag to 1234 initially should happen in the method but outside of the sub-methods (or whatever you want to call them) rather than in the viewDidLoad?  If so, why would this make the iPhone/iPod start going one sub-method thing at a time rather than two?  Thanks!

Comment: Because you're calling the method for tag `1234` or whatever tag, and you're changing the tag while the button is still pressed so the next method is fire.  I imagine if you actually held the button down long enough, numerous methods would fire.  If you move the changing of the tag into the action fire as the button is released, you shouldn't get double method calls.  The pile full of fake method calls is sloppy...

Comment: While that makes a lot of sense, I just tried holding down the UIButton a few times for about 20 seconds each on my iPod Touch 5, and it still behaved exactly the same, so I do not think that explains the issue... I'm still very confused.  Thank you for the help though!  Also if you have an answer please post it as an answer, not a comment, so I can mark you as correct and give you rep points for your trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I ran it on my iPod Touch and it worked fantastically- but only when not plugged into the computer.  I think that Xcode is somehow messing it up because the app works when the iPod is unattached but not when it is attached and the computer is logging results.  However, all that matters is that it works unattached, so while the reason for the error is still unknown it is solved and therefore unimportant.  However, if anyone comes up with a solution that actually explains the issue I will of course make that be the official "answer" of the question.  Possibly the issue was that it was building for the wrong build settings, like Arm__ (where in __ are the wrong letters- not sure which are correct and which are not).  Anyways, the issue appears to be strangely solved.